# Game of Life program, help needed with user input

Tags: c++

I have a basic 'Game of Life' program in C++ and I need to alter to accept user input for both the size of the grid and the parameters for how many neighbors will make a cell alive or dead. For right now, I am focusing on the user input for the size of the grid, but I'm having problems with 'undeclared identifiers' for the maxrow and maxcol variables. Here is the code, and at the bottom is the function I made to accept user input. The program works as is, but when I try and implement the user input function it gives me all those errors. I know I have to delete the constant ints inside the header file, but I think my errors are coming from certain functions not understanding what maxrow and maxcol are, for example the 'instructions' function. How can I implement it in a way where the variables will be recognized throughout the entire program? Thank you for any help.

**life.h**

```
#ifndef LIFE_H
#define LIFE_H

const int maxrow = 20, maxcol = 60; 

class Life
{
  public:
    Life(void);
    ~Life(void);
    void initialize();
    void print();
    void update();
    int getNeighbor_count(int, int);
    void instructions();
    bool user_says_yes();

  private:
    int grid[maxrow+2][maxcol+2];   // allows for two extra rows and columns
    int neighbor_count(int row, int col);
};

#endif
```

**life.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream> 
#include "life.h"
using namespace std;


Life::Life()
{
}


Life::~Life(void)
{
}


int Life::neighbor_count(int row, int col)
/* Pre: The Life object contains a configuration, and the coordinates row and col define a cell inside its hedge.
Returns: The number of living neighbors of the specified */
{
    int i, j;
    int count = 0;
    for(i = row-1; i <= row+1; i++)
      for(j = col-1; j <= col+1; j++)
       count += grid[i][j]; // Increase if neighbor is alive.
    count -= grid[row][col]; // Reduce count, cell is not its own neighbor.
    return count;

}

void Life::update( )
/*Pre: The Life object contains a configuration.
  Post: The Life object contains the next generation of configuration.*/
{
   int row, col;
   int new_grid[maxrow + 2][maxcol + 2];
   for(row = 1; row <= maxrow; row++)
      for(col = 1; col <= maxcol; col++)
         switch (neighbor_count(row, col)) {
           case 2: // Status stays the same.
             new_grid[row][col] = grid[row][col];             
             break;
           case 3: // Cell is now alive.
             new_grid[row][col] = 1;
             break;
           default: // Cell is now dead
             new_grid[row][col] = 0;
         }
  // Copy new configuration back to original 
  for(row = 1; row <= maxrow; row++)
      for(col = 1; col <= maxcol; col++)
          grid[row][col] = new_grid[row][col];
}


void Life::initialize( )
/* Pre: None.
   Post: The Life object contains a configuration specified by the user.*/
{
   int row, col;
   for(row = 0; row <= maxrow+1; row++)
      for(col = 0; col <= maxcol+1; col++)
    grid[row][col] = 0;
   cout <<"List the coordinates for living cells." << endl;
   cout << "Terminate the list with the the special pair -1 -1"<< endl;
   cin >> row >> col;
   while (row != -1 || col != -1) 
   {
      if(row >= 1 && row <= maxrow)
         if(col >= 1 && col <= maxcol)
             grid[row][col] = 1;
         else
             cout << "Column " << col << " is out of range." << endl;
      else
             cout << "Row " << row << " is out of range." << endl;
      cin >> row >> col;
   }
}

void Life::print( )
/*  Pre: The Life object contains a configuration.
    Post: The configuration is written for the user.
*/
{
   int row, col;
   cout << "\nThe current Life configurations is: "<< endl;
   for(row = 1; row <= maxrow; row++) {
      for(col = 1; col <= maxcol; col++)
         if(grid[row][col] == 1) cout << '*';
         else cout << ' ';
      cout << endl;
   }
   cout << endl;
}
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream> 
#include "life.h"
using namespace std;

void instructions();
bool user_says_yes();

void Life::instructions( )
/* Pre: None.
   Post: Instructions for using the Life program have been printed.*/
{
   cout << "Welcome to Conway's game of Life." << endl;
   cout << "This game uses a grid of size "
        << maxrow << " by " << maxcol << " in which" << endl;
   cout << "each cell can either be occupied by an organism or not." << endl;
   cout << "The occupied cells change from generation to generation" << endl;
   cout << "according to the number of neighboring cells ";
   cout << "which are alive." << endl;
}

bool Life::user_says_yes()
{
   int c;
   bool initial_response = true;
   do { // Loop until an appropriate input is received.
      if(initial_response)
         cout << "Would you like to see the next generation (y,n)? " << flush;
      else
         cout << "Respond with either y or n: " << flush;
      do { // Ignore white space.
         c = cin.get( );
      } while (c == '\n' || c == ' ' || c == '\t');
      initial_response = false;
  } while (c != 'y' && c != 'Y' && c != 'n' && c != 'N');
 return (c == 'y' || c == 'Y');
}

int Life::getNeighbor_count(int row, int col)
{
    return neighbor_count(row, col);
}


int main()// driver for neighbor_count( )
/* Pre: None.
   Post: Verifies that the method neighbor_count( )returns the correct values.
   Uses: The class Life and its method initialize( ).
*/
{
    Life configuration;
    configuration.instructions();
    configuration.initialize();
   do{
   for(int row = 1; row <= maxrow; row++){
      for(int col = 1; col <= maxrow; col++)
         cout << configuration.getNeighbor_count(row,col) << " ";
         cout << endl;
   }
   configuration.print();
   configuration.update();
   }while(configuration.user_says_yes());

}
```

**user input function for max column and max row**

```
void getGridParameters(int& maxrow, int& maxcol)
{
    cout << "Enter number of rows for the grid: ";
    cin >> maxrow;
    cout << "Enter number of columns for the grid ";
    cin >> maxcol;
}
```

Comment: What are the errors you get?

Comment: If I delete the constant ints in the header and add the function, I get a bunch of these:  
  
     life.h(18): error C2065: 'maxrow' : undeclared identifier  
     life.h(18): error C2065: 'maxcol' : undeclared identifier  
  
but for just about every instance, including inside life.cpp

Comment: Simply make them non-const members of the `Life` class.

Comment: @CareyGregory: Not that simple. They're currently array bounds.

Comment: @MSalters - True, but that just requires a single array allocation and knowing how to index into it as a 2D array. Problems like this are why people should learn C before learning C++.

Comment: I have come back to this problem and I am still having trouble. I'm more than lost to say the least. The instructions say "In order to make this work, you will need to modify the Life class so that it has more constructor parameters and uses a two-dimensional dynamic array." Any help?

Answer (score 0):

The old way of make variables seen by any other functions is  to declare them as `global` variables which is bad.   For `instruction` function to `understand` maxrow and maxcol, you can pass these values to that funciton, like this

```
void instructions(int maxrow, int maxcol );
```

If you want to change the value passed in, you can pass by reference

```
void instructions(int &maxrow, int& maxcol );
```

(although for this function, you may not need pass by reference.)

Comment: That passes by value.  How would the calling function get the results back?

Comment: you can pass by reference. `void instructions(int &maxrow, int & maxcol );`

Comment: Well, right, but in your answer you're passing by value.  Might want to edit that.

Comment: Could you expand more on how I would use this? So I deleted the constant ints in the header, added the function to main.cpp, would I need to do something similar for the functions that use maxrow and maxcol in life.cpp?

Comment: yes , you need to do that for other functions. but as suggested by Jack, you may want to declare them as members.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your grid is declared as `int grid[maxrow+2][maxcol+2];`, which requires `maxrow` and `maxcol` to be constants.

C++ has a type for runtime-sized arrays, `std::vector< >`. Since you have a 2D grid, you need a vector of vectors: `std::vector<std::vector<int>>`. Using `grid` remains the same: `grid[i][j]` still works. But you have to set the initial size:

```
void Life::setupGrid()
{
  // I've got maxrow rows, and each row has maxcol columns.
  grid.resize(maxrow, std::vector<int>(maxcol));
}
```

Now there's no requirement for maxrow and maxcol to be constant anymore. As a benefit, you can now say `for (auto& row : grid) { for (auto& cell: row) { /** stuff **/ } }` to do something to each cell.

Comment: Wouldn't this require me to alter much of the code inside life.cpp?

Answer (score -1):

`maxrow` and `maxcol` are `const` and they are declared in a header file. This boils down in them disappearing as variables in your compiled binary as you stated.

To make them variable you should declare them as member variables of your `Life` class:

```
class Life {
  private:
    int maxcol, maxrows;
    ..
}
```

Since they'll become non-constant you can't declare a bidimensional array directly in your `Life` class, you will need to allocate it dynamically, eg:

```
int **grid = new int*[maxrows];
for (int i = 0; i < maxrows; ++i)
  grid[i] = new int[maxcols];
```

This will require you to deallocate memory in `Life` destructor. Another solution would be to have a single dimension array, eg `int **grid = new int[maxrows*maxcols]` to simplify allocation but it would require to change indexing function.

Regarding how to store them, since they'll become part of Life class then you can directly save the input value in them:

```
void Life::getNeighbor_count() {
  cin >> maxrows;
  cin >> maxcols;
  allocateGrid();
}
```

Comment: I'm kind of confused as to what you are doing here. I see you declared the maxrow and maxcol variables directly in the class, along with the two-dimensional array, but why are the user inputs for grid parameters within getNeighbor_count() ?

Comment: Downvoting, not because the initial diagnosis (which is correct) but because you're suggesting that a beginner should use `new[]` instead of `std::vector`.

Comment: @MSalters: A beginner should at least understand what a dynamically allocated array is and how it works before studying STL. In this particular situation a `std::vector` is not so easier to approach than a `new[]`: you need a `std::vector` of `std::vector` and you need to fill each one (or at least reserve space for a correct approach) so while I respect your point of view the reason, imho, is not worth a down vote. In any case why should you study templates before how heap and dynamic allocation works?

Comment: STL is meant to make your life easier, not equivalent. If you don't need a dynamic data structure, which is not the case since here it is initialized once, there is no practical benefit in using the features of a `vector` with exception to the one given by the fact that it would be a member variable and not a member pointer to variable.

Comment: @Jack: that's becoming a rare opinion nowadays. See e.g. Andrew Koenig's Accelerated C++. Note that arrays are the odd generic type. Whereas every other generic (template) type is spelled `Something<T>`, arrays are spelled `T[N]`. Initializing the `grid` is literally a one-liner. And beginners should learn how to _use_ templates early on because that's a far more useful skill than using the heap. See Herb Sutters GOTW articles for more background.